# Ground/floor plane not visible

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi, the ground plane in this world file appears to be not visible:

```
<rendering:ogre>
   <ambient>0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5</ambient>
   <sky>
      <material>Gazebo/CloudySky</material>
   </sky>
   <grid>false</grid>
   <maxUpdateRate>10.</maxUpdateRate>
   <shadowTechnique>none</shadowTechnique>
   <shadows>false</shadows>
</rendering:ogre>

<!-- ground plane -->
   <model:physical name="gplane">
      <xyz>0 0 0</xyz>    
      <rpy>0 0 0</rpy>
      <static>true</static>

      <body:plane name="plane">
         <geom:plane name="plane">
            <laserRetro>2000.0</laserRetro>
            <mu1>50.0</mu1>
            <mu2>50.0</mu2>
            <kp>1000000000.0</kp>
            <kd>1.0</kd>
            <normal>0 0 1</normal>
            <size>100 100</size>
            <segments>10 10</segments>
            <uvTile>100 100</uvTile>
            <material>Gazebo/GrayGrid</material>
         </geom:plane>
      </body:plane>
   </model:physical>
```

Might this be because it is transparant? How can this be resolved?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1246/ground/floor-plane-not-visible/) by [bcoenen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/197/bcoenen/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-02-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bcoenen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/197/bcoenen/) on 2013-02-07**:
I'm using version 1.0.2. How do I set the material correct? Is GreyGrid the correct material name? Because if I change it from Gray to Grey the problem is still present...

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-02-07**:
Is that version 1.0.2 as reported by ROS? The string "Gazebo/GrayGrid" refers to a material script in a file called gazebo.material (or Gazebo.material depending on your version). This file should exist in your `GAZEBO_RESOURCE_PATH`. You can also check `~/.gazebo/orgre.log` for errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Indeed GrayGrid or GreyGrid was not present in the Gazebo.material file. I finally solved by setting it to Grey and by defining the material as visual:

```
    <visual>
      <material>Gazebo/Grey</material>
    </visual>
```

---

Originally posted by [bcoenen](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/197/bcoenen/) with karma: 16 on 2013-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It looks like your using a world file that dates from pre-gazebo 1.0. Are you also using a version of gazebo from that era?

If so, I would make sure the GreyGrid material is correct.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-02-06

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1